# Объединение XPATH

Tags: парсер, xpath

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как объединить th и td из таблицы в одном Xpath?

```
<tr>
 <th class="hide_th_3">Width (mm)</th>
 <th class="hide_th_4">Length (m)</th>
 <th class="hide_th_5">Type</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="hide_td_3">60</td>
 <td class="hide_td_4">40</td>
 <td class="hide_td_5">Iekšdarbiem</td>
</tr>
```

Хочу чтобы получилось в таком виде:
Width (m): 60
Length (m): 40
Type: Iekšdarbiem

Comment: С помощью `|` или `or`.

Comment: Тогда получится вот так: - Width (m) - Length (m) - Type - 60 - 40 - Iekšdarbiem. Т.е. сначала соберутся все th, а потом td

Answer (score 0):

**xpath 2.0** (небраузерная версия):

с помощью метода `string-join`:

```
string-join(//table//th[count(//table//th/../preceding-sibling::*) + number(boolean(//table//th/../preceding-sibling::*))], ': ', //table//td[count(//table//td/../preceding-sibling::*) + number(boolean(//table//td/../preceding-sibling::*))], '\n')
```

**xpath 1.0** (браузерная версия):

доступен только метод `concat`, который возвращает лишь первое вхождение, так что в этом случае нужно получить количество th и td, и если они равны (вам ведь пары значений нужны), то в цикле (через доступный язык программирования) прогнать получение текста по индексу каждой пары:

```
concat(//table//th[${i}], ': ', //table//td[${i}])
```